# SBT 1.2.8 Resolving key references hanging

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt1.0

We recently upgraded our sbt build from `0.13.x` to `1.2.8` from then on our build agents are often (not always ) hangs right after

`Resolving key references (11281 settings) ...`

In thread dump I see following lines

`- locked <0x00000000800058c0> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)`

`- waiting on <0x00000000800058c0> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)`

Is it a bug? if not what am I doing wrong? Can you please advice?

### Environment details

- OS `Linux aldburg 3.13.0-32-generic #57~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:20 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
- SBT launcher version `1.2.8`
- SBT project version `1.2.8`
- SBT Plugins we use are

```
addSbtPlugin("org.scoverage" % "sbt-scoverage" % "1.5.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-site" % "1.3.1")
addSbtPlugin("com.waioeka.sbt" % "cucumber-plugin" % "0.1.7")
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-unidoc" % "0.4.1")
addSbtPlugin("org.scalastyle" %% "scalastyle-sbt-plugin" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("io.spray" % "sbt-revolver" % "0.9.0")
addSbtPlugin("org.scalariform" % "sbt-scalariform" % "1.8.2")
addSbtPlugin("com.github.gseitz" % "sbt-release" % "1.0.7")
addSbtPlugin("de.heikoseeberger" % "sbt-header" % "4.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.lightbend.sbt" % "sbt-aspectj" % "0.11.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.3.2")
addSbtPlugin("pl.project13.scala" % "sbt-jmh" % "0.3.4")
```

### Thread dump

```
Full thread dump OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.111-b14 mixed mode):

"Attach Listener" #51 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbc40001000 nid=0x10bd waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"pool-4-thread-8" #50 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbc0c00e000 nid=0xf6c in Object.wait() [0x00007fbc45534000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at $0e82cce6ec5c385cb470$.$anonfun$v1$10(build.sbt:58)
    at $0e82cce6ec5c385cb470$$$Lambda$2732/1436136891.apply(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings.$anonfun$constant$1(INode.scala:204)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$$Lambda$1613/382762227.apply(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode.evaluate0(INode.scala:221)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$INode.evaluate(INode.scala:164)
    - locked <0x0000000083884fc8> (a sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings.$anonfun$submitEvaluate$1(INode.scala:87)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$$Lambda$1624/2021540695.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings.sbt$internal$util$EvaluateSettings$$run0(INode.scala:98)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$$anon$3.run(INode.scala:94)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-4-thread-7" #49 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbc89f2d800 nid=0xf6b in Object.wait() [0x00007fbc45230000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at Dependencies$.<init>(Dependencies.scala:144)
    at Dependencies$.<clinit>(Dependencies.scala)
    at $0e82cce6ec5c385cb470$.$anonfun$common$10(build.sbt:81)
    at $0e82cce6ec5c385cb470$$$Lambda$2744/908744222.apply(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings.$anonfun$constant$1(INode.scala:204)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$$Lambda$1613/382762227.apply(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode.evaluate0(INode.scala:221)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$INode.evaluate(INode.scala:164)
    - locked <0x000000008388f6c0> (a sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings.$anonfun$submitEvaluate$1(INode.scala:87)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$$Lambda$1624/2021540695.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings.sbt$internal$util$EvaluateSettings$$run0(INode.scala:98)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$$anon$3.run(INode.scala:94)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-4-thread-6" #48 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbc89f2c800 nid=0xf6a in Object.wait() [0x00007fbc45332000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at $0e82cce6ec5c385cb470$.$anonfun$support$1(build.sbt:163)
    at $0e82cce6ec5c385cb470$$$Lambda$2734/1113898680.apply(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings.$anonfun$constant$1(INode.scala:204)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$$Lambda$1613/382762227.apply(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode.evaluate0(INode.scala:221)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$INode.evaluate(INode.scala:164)
    - locked <0x00000000838c9798> (a sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings.$anonfun$submitEvaluate$1(INode.scala:87)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$$Lambda$1624/2021540695.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings.sbt$internal$util$EvaluateSettings$$run0(INode.scala:98)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$$anon$3.run(INode.scala:94)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-4-thread-5" #47 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbc89f2b800 nid=0xf69 in Object.wait() [0x00007fbc44a2a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at Dependencies$Compile$.<init>(Dependencies.scala:42)
    at Dependencies$Compile$.<clinit>(Dependencies.scala)
    at $0e82cce6ec5c385cb470$.$anonfun$test_server$4(build.sbt:176)
    at $0e82cce6ec5c385cb470$$$Lambda$2715/684426930.apply(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings.$anonfun$constant$1(INode.scala:204)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$$Lambda$1613/382762227.apply(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode.evaluate0(INode.scala:221)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$INode.evaluate(INode.scala:164)
    - locked <0x0000000083a9c6c0> (a sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings.$anonfun$submitEvaluate$1(INode.scala:87)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$$Lambda$1624/2021540695.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings.sbt$internal$util$EvaluateSettings$$run0(INode.scala:98)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$$anon$3.run(INode.scala:94)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-4-thread-4" #46 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbc0800d000 nid=0xf68 in Object.wait() [0x00007fbc4502f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at $0e82cce6ec5c385cb470$.$anonfun$test_utils$1(build.sbt:208)
    at $0e82cce6ec5c385cb470$$$Lambda$2751/171063899.apply(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings.$anonfun$constant$1(INode.scala:204)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$$Lambda$1613/382762227.apply(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode.evaluate0(INode.scala:221)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$INode.evaluate(INode.scala:164)
    - locked <0x0000000084031dd0> (a sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings.$anonfun$submitEvaluate$1(INode.scala:87)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$$Lambda$1624/2021540695.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings.sbt$internal$util$EvaluateSettings$$run0(INode.scala:98)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$$anon$3.run(INode.scala:94)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-4-thread-3" #45 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbc89f2a800 nid=0xf67 in Object.wait() [0x00007fbc45433000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at $0e82cce6ec5c385cb470$.$anonfun$benchmark$1(build.sbt:154)
    at $0e82cce6ec5c385cb470$$$Lambda$2797/2015110295.apply(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings.$anonfun$constant$1(INode.scala:204)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$$Lambda$1613/382762227.apply(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode.evaluate0(INode.scala:221)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$INode.evaluate(INode.scala:164)
    - locked <0x00000000842c3310> (a sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings.$anonfun$submitEvaluate$1(INode.scala:87)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$$Lambda$1624/2021540695.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings.sbt$internal$util$EvaluateSettings$$run0(INode.scala:98)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$$anon$3.run(INode.scala:94)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-4-thread-2" #44 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbc89f2a000 nid=0xf66 in Object.wait() [0x00007fbc44f2e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at $0e82cce6ec5c385cb470$.$anonfun$cucumber$2(build.sbt:195)
    at $0e82cce6ec5c385cb470$$$Lambda$2794/1142350221.apply(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings.$anonfun$constant$1(INode.scala:204)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$$Lambda$1613/382762227.apply(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode.evaluate0(INode.scala:221)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$INode.evaluate(INode.scala:164)
    - locked <0x0000000083f0b728> (a sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings.$anonfun$submitEvaluate$1(INode.scala:87)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$$Lambda$1624/2021540695.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings.sbt$internal$util$EvaluateSettings$$run0(INode.scala:98)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$$anon$3.run(INode.scala:94)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"pool-4-thread-1" #43 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbc89f28000 nid=0xf65 in Object.wait() [0x00007fbc45130000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at $0e82cce6ec5c385cb470$.$anonfun$domain$1(build.sbt:147)
    at $0e82cce6ec5c385cb470$$$Lambda$2733/1341548823.apply(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings.$anonfun$constant$1(INode.scala:204)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$$Lambda$1613/382762227.apply(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode.evaluate0(INode.scala:221)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$INode.evaluate(INode.scala:164)
    - locked <0x0000000084031e40> (a sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$MixedNode)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings.$anonfun$submitEvaluate$1(INode.scala:87)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$$Lambda$1624/2021540695.apply$mcV$sp(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings.sbt$internal$util$EvaluateSettings$$run0(INode.scala:98)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings$$anon$3.run(INode.scala:94)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Log4j2-TF-1-AsyncLogger[AsyncContext@64bf3bbf]-1" #13 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbc8a2df800 nid=0xf38 waiting on condition [0x00007fbc6126c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x000000008000b4e8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at com.lmax.disruptor.TimeoutBlockingWaitStrategy.waitFor(TimeoutBlockingWaitStrategy.java:38)
    at com.lmax.disruptor.ProcessingSequenceBarrier.waitFor(ProcessingSequenceBarrier.java:56)
    at com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.processEvents(BatchEventProcessor.java:159)
    at com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.run(BatchEventProcessor.java:125)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

"Service Thread" #9 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbc88213000 nid=0xf36 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C1 CompilerThread3" #8 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbc88205800 nid=0xf35 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread2" #7 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbc88201000 nid=0xf34 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" #6 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbc881ff800 nid=0xf33 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" #5 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbc881fc800 nid=0xf32 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" #4 daemon prio=9 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbc881fa800 nid=0xf31 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" #3 daemon prio=8 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbc881d2800 nid=0xf30 in Object.wait() [0x00007fbc62ceb000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x0000000080003910> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    - locked <0x0000000080003910> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:164)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler" #2 daemon prio=10 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbc881ce000 nid=0xf2e in Object.wait() [0x00007fbc62dec000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000000800058c0> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference.tryHandlePending(Reference.java:191)
    - locked <0x00000000800058c0> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:153)

"main" #1 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbc8800a000 nid=0xf20 waiting on condition [0x00007fbc91ed0000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000084031e88> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at sbt.internal.util.EvaluateSettings.run(INode.scala:72)
    at sbt.internal.util.Init.applyInits(Settings.scala:286)
    at sbt.internal.util.Init.make(Settings.scala:208)
    at sbt.internal.util.Init.make$(Settings.scala:199)
    at sbt.Def$.make(Def.scala:20)
    at sbt.internal.Load$.$anonfun$apply$5(Load.scala:266)
    at sbt.internal.Load$$$Lambda$1561/1579610605.apply(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.internal.Load$.timed(Load.scala:1395)
    at sbt.internal.Load$.apply(Load.scala:261)
    at sbt.internal.Load$.defaultLoad(Load.scala:69)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.liftedTree1$1(Main.scala:829)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.doLoadProject(Main.scala:829)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$.$anonfun$loadProjectImpl$2(Main.scala:800)
    at sbt.BuiltinCommands$$$Lambda$380/810169941.apply(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$4(Command.scala:142)
    at sbt.Command$$$Lambda$330/1723848804.apply(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$2(Command.scala:137)
    at sbt.Command$$$Lambda$356/1859823482.apply(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.Command$.process(Command.scala:181)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.processCommand(MainLoop.scala:151)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$2(MainLoop.scala:139)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$$Lambda$311/198374825.apply(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.State$$anon$1.runCmd$1(State.scala:246)
    at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:250)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$1(MainLoop.scala:139)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$$Lambda$310/1620187937.apply(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:139)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:132)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1(MainLoop.scala:110)
    at sbt.MainLoop$$$Lambda$303/1924802798.apply(Unknown Source)
    at sbt.io.Using.apply(Using.scala:22)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:104)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:59)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:44)
    at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:35)
    at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:138)
    at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:89)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:56)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:18)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)

"VM Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbc881c6800 nid=0xf2d runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbc8801f000 nid=0xf21 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbc88020800 nid=0xf22 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbc88022800 nid=0xf27 runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbc88024000 nid=0xf28 runnable 

"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbc88026000 nid=0xf29 runnable 

"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbc88027800 nid=0xf2a runnable 

"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbc88029800 nid=0xf2b runnable 

"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbc8802b000 nid=0xf2c runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" os_prio=0 tid=0x00007fbc88215800 nid=0xf37 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 5542
```

Comment: That's a lot of plugins. One troubleshooting route would be to bisect your plugins list: remove half of them, see if the problem goes away. If it doesn't, remove half of the remaining ones, and so on. If you can reproduce the problem without any plugins at all, then you've made good progress on tracking down the cause. And/or, try running sbt with `-debug` and see if that produces any additional helpful information.

Comment: @SethTisue thanks for the reply

Answer (score 3):

Our build server is using different `sbt-launcher` (`0.13.x`) than one provided in the agent.

In our case, issue is fixed with the following steps :

- Pointing launcher version to `sbt-launcher 1.2.8`
- Removed sbt cache `rm -rf ~/.sbt` (make sure, take backups of global `.sbt` files and `.credentials` file etc..)
- Removed ivy cache `rm -rf ~/.ivy2/cache`
- `export SBT_OPTS="-Dscala.concurrent.context.maxThreads=1"` (out of 5 agents, i have to do this in only one agent)

I am not sure whether it fixes for everyone or not.